# nginx rewrite rule for a specific location

Tags: php, nginx, mod-rewrite

I have nginx server and want to rewrite my url who comes from a PHP script located in the index.php.

I get a URL from the script that doesn't really exist on my server.

Like the follow example: **mydomain.tld/location/that/doesn/t/exist/**
then I rewrite this url who doesn't exist with a rewrite rule in my nginx conf-file like following:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /welcome.php last;
}
```

Then I can see the welcome.php file. This works like a charm.

But If I want to adapt it for a specific location like this:

```
location /anotherfolder {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /another.php last;
}
```

I always get am 404 Not found error.

Log output doesn't really help me.

> 2018/06/23 17:57:06 [error] 29928#29928: *1 "/var/www/html/mydomain.tld/anotherfolder/location/that/dosen/t/exist/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory) client:127.0.0.1, server: mydomain.tld, request: "GET /anotherfolder/location/that/dosen/t/exist/ HTTP/2.0", host: "mydomain.tld"

I don't get it, why it works in my root location (/var/www/html/mydomain.tld/)
but not in the other one.

Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: Your *regular expression* does not match the URI. `/anotherfolder/location/that/dosen/t/exist/` has six path elements, whereas `^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$` expects only five.

Comment: the folder "_anotherfolder_" does exitst, and there is the _index.php_ who creats the other 5 path elements.
I want to rewrite the 5 path elemtents to _mydomain.tld/anotherfolder/another.php_

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nginx conf-file into the "*location /anotherfolder*" segment

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
}
```

Comment: When I add this to my config and I visit mydomain.tld/anotherfolder
the index.php get instant downloaded.
Also the error 404 Not found is still present when I visit mydomain.tld/anotherfolder/location/that/dosen/t/exist/